# VSTS 2017: batch scripts is supported in Functional Test?

Tags: azure-pipelines-build-task

My partial build definition is as following：
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/roBmM.png “Build Definition”

And Error shows that: 
Error : No tests were discovered from the specified test sources
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/olrSF.png “Error”

And I have already copied test.bat in C:\Tests\,
Are there any errors in my build definitions? And batch scripts is supported in Functional Test? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The batch file is not supported in [functional test](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/test/run-functional-tests). You need to make sure the tests can be run in Visual Studio or via vstest.console.exe.